# Getting File Name Details from Image File

Tags: php, extract, filenames

I am looking for a way to grab details from a file name to insert it into my database. My issue is that the file name is always a bit different, even if it has a pattern.

Examples:
arizona-911545_1920.jpg
bass-guitar-913092_1280.jpg
eiffel-tower-905039_1280.jpg
new-york-city-78181_1920.jpg

The first part is always what the image is about, for example arizona, bass guitar, eiffel tower, new york city followed by a unique id and the width of the image.

What I am after would be extracting:

name id and width

So if I run for example getInfo('arizona-911545_1920.jpg');

it would return something like

```
$extractedname
$extractedid
$extractedwidth
```

so I could easily save this in my mysql database like

```
INSERT into images VALUES ('$extractedname','$extractedid','$extractedwidth')
```

What bothers me most is that image names can be longer, for example new-york-city-bank or even new-york-city-bank-window so I need a safe method to get the name, no matter how long it would be.

I do know how to replace the - between the name, that's not an issue. I am really just searching for a way to extract the details I mentioned above.

I would appreciate it if someone could enlighten me on how to solve this.

Thanks :)

Comment: This may sound embarassingly simple, but just read till you hit a digit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Extracting the data you are looking for would be best via a regex pattern like the following:

```
(.+)-(\d+_(\d+))
```

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/oM5bS8/2

```
preg_match('(.+)-(\d+_(\d+))',"<filename>", $matches);
$extractedname = $matches[1];
$extractedid = $matches[2];
$extractedwidth = $matches[3];
```

EDIT - Just reread the question and you are looking for extraction techniques not how to post the image from a page to your backend. I will leave this here for reference.

When you post files via a form in html to a PHP backend there are few items that are needed.

1) You need to ensure that your form type is multi-part so that it knows to pass the files along.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2) Your php backend needs to iterate over the files and save them accordingly.

Here is a sample of how to iterate over the files that are being submitted.

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) { 
        $n = $file['name']; 
        $s = $file['size']; 
        if (!$n) continue; 
        echo "File: $n ($s bytes)"; 
    }
```

Comment: Are you posting some question-non-related info about file uploads? How's that an answer?

Comment: Yep, that is because I misread the question, I added an edit with the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way in this case is to use regexp, for example:

```
preg_match('/^(\D+)-(\d+)_(\d+)/', $filename, $matches);
// $matches[1] - name
// $matches[2] - id
// $matches[3] - width
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the main Idea.

Let's pick a file first.

Filename will be "bass-guitar-913092_1280.jpg"

First of all we will Split this with **explode**, to **dot( . )** in variable **$Temp**

This will give us an Array of **bass-guitar-913092_1280** and **jpg**

We will choose to have **the first Item** of the array to continue since is the name we are interested in so we will get it with **$Temp[0]**

After this we will Split it Again this time to **( _ )**.

Now we will have an array of **bass-guitar-913092** and **1280**

The Second value of the Array is what We need so we will pick it with **$Temp[1]**

The Last part is simple as the others, We will now Split the file name **$Temp[0]** with **( - )** We will get the Last value of it which is the id **$Temp[count($Temp)-1]** and we will remove this from the array list, and Connect everything else with **implode** and the delimeter we want

Now we can use also the Function **ucwords** to Capitalize every first letter of each word on the main name.

In the following code, there are 2 ways of getting the name, one with lowercase letters, and one with uppercase first letters of each word, uncomment what you want.

### **Edited Code as a Function**

```
<?php 
function ExtractFileInfo($fileName) {
    $Temp = explode(".",$fileName);
    $Temp = explode("_",$Temp[0]);
    $width = $Temp[1];
    $Temp = explode("-",$Temp[0]);
    $id = $Temp[count($Temp)-1];
    unset($Temp[count($Temp-1)]);
    // If you want to have the name with lowercase letters Uncomment the Following:
    //$name = implode(" ",$Temp);
    // If you Want to Capitalize every first letter of the name Uncomment the Following:
    //$name = ucwords(implode(" ",$Temp));

    return array($name,$id,$width);
}
?>
```

This will return an Array of 3 Elements Name, Id and Width

Comment: Downvoting an answer, just because is not using Regular Expressions is Ridiculous. Just because you are familiar with them, doesn't mean that everybody else should be or doesn't mean that this answer is not working, or it is unacceptable. It's just a quick example of how to do it. This is just an alternate answer.

Comment: I think your solution has overhead compared to regexp, but I didn't downvote it.

Comment: Regular Expressions are more Time Saving, but for the users that are not familiar with these, this example will make them understand what they are doing, and not just a simple copy paste of an "ancient voodoo spell" for them.

Comment: I am thankful for the answer as it explains a lot. I just have to be fair and select the first answer because it does also work. However, the explaining here was more helpful, so thanks for that

Comment: You can always vote up for the Useful Answers :) Happy to help. Edit: Also you don't have to select always the first working answer, but the answer helped you the most. :)